# How do I ensure all dlc is downloaded for my Xbox 360 game?

Tags: xbox-360

I decided to give Fable 2 another playthrough after years away from it.  I have all of the dlc, including the little stuff.   I installed the game to a memory unit I have plugged into the console because I would rather have it on flash memory than the aging HDD and the DVD drive is now old enough that it makes a lot of noise during play.    I also want to put all of the dlc on the flash disk.   I intend to do the same with Fable 3.

Do I need to trigger individual downloads for each dlc item, and then transfer them to the flash, or will the Microsoft Live servers detect my licenses and download these automatically when I install or play the game?  If they do, will I need to move the downloaded content manually to the flash once this completes?

Update: I chatted with a Microsoft rep via support chat.  The rep indicated that all of the DLC should be available once the game installs.  They also had trouble understanding the difference between loading a game and installing a game and used the terms interchangeably in explanations.  Can anyone with experience clarify whether or not I need to install the DLC components manually?